# Ошибка Git, не могу загрузить свои файлы на свой GitHub

Tags: javascript, html, css, git, github

Ошибка заключаеться вот в чём:
Я со старого ноутбука создал html, css, и js. Ну и другие файлы тоже, но это не важно. И, я соединил их  с гитом.
После этого, я свою папку с файлами перекинул себе на гугл диск, и уже оттуда я перекачал их к себе на другой комп. Но, я не могу эти файлы соединить со своим GitHub-ом, почему - не знаю.
Вот скриншот (GitHub) - [image: Мой гитхаб]

А вот скриншот терминала - [image: Терминал]

И, после того как я ввёл команду `git push --set -u origin main` , выдало ещё и это - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я очень прошу, если вы знаете, что мне надо сделать - помогите, пожалуйста. Я так уже 2 дня сижу, и не могу ничего с этим поделать.

upd - написал git pull, выдало вот это - [image: терминал]

Comment: вам же пишет - сделайте git pull - на сервере лежит более свежая версия, чем у Вас

Comment: @KoVadim Написал, вот что выдало - https://i.ibb.co/K9gzMMk/5.png

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: там все пишется - выставляйте теперь для pull ветку.

Comment: Т.е, я зря добавил изображения к вопросу? Не понял вас.

Comment: все нормально сделали. Можно было и текстом, но не все умеют копировать текст с виндовой консоли

Comment: @KoVadim А, понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хоть один раз отправили файлы в Git репозиторий, скачать их можно с помощью команды [clone](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-Git-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F#r_git_cloning) `git clone адрес-репозитория`. И не нужно создавать дополнительную копию где-то на сторонних ресурсах типа Google Disk. Git уже является этим репозиторием.

Но если у вас уже присутствует копия на диске и вы хотите обновить последние данные, тогда нужно набрать след. команду: `git pull origin`, это позволит скачать все данные и ветки с удаленного репозитория.

Если необходимо скачать в ветку, тогда `git pull origin <название ветки>`.

`git pull origin master` или `git pull origin main`

Для закачки новых изменений в Git репозиторий: `git push origin <название ветки>`

```bsh
# В ветку master
git push origin master

# В ветку main
git push origin main

# В ветку develop
git push origin develop
```

Вот [здесь](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2) доступна бесплатная книга на русском

Comment: Всё удалил, и сделал так, как вы и сказали. И действительно это помогло, не нужно было с кодами возиться. Но мне всё равно нужно было устанавливать адрес своего гитхаба, через `git set-url`, но всё же спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил свою проблему.  Вот что я прописал -
`git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories`
`git set-url -add origin (url моего гитхаба`
`git pull --set -u origin (url моего гитхаба) main`
`git merge main (Что я сделал тут точно не помню)`
`git add .`
`git commit (Дальше сделал ком.)`
`git push`